# Magento - Enabling cache takes me to 404 page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to enable cache in magento 1.7.0.2 but it takes me to the 404 page and after refreshing the page, cache is not enabled. Please help.

Comment: Did you also rebuild all the items listed on the cache page? I ask only because I did exactly this once! Make change, clear cache, 404. Rebuild indexes, then good.

Answer (score 3):

Hi @Harshad Manjre....

First of all, You should be enable the `magento cache` in admin.

`system->cache management->`then select all cache details and refresh it..
    then `system->index management->`then select all index and re-index it..

further,you should follow this...
  folder structure for clear cache and index management..

> magento(scratch)->var folder->lock folder->select all files and
>   deleted it...
>       magento(scratch)->var folder->cache folder->select all files and deleted it...

then,make sure that u first delete all the cookies of your browser.then logout admin panel and login once again....
Its more useful for your needs...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was in a hurry so I installed fresh magento and then uploaded the theme and other required files again. And now the cache is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

When You are on admin side of **magento** and try to enable the **magento cache**. make sure that u first delete all the cookies of your browser. For Firefox there is a short key which is **Ctrl+Shift+Del**. This will open the popup where you must cleared your **cookies**. Then Refresh Your Page. This will asking you to again **Login Information**. After **login** go to cache management and enable it. This will work for me as well as for you..
Due to magento using extreme caching its happened sometimes that the browser cookies resides some info related to cache. Thats why its happened.
Let me know if this method will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried what you suggested, but not working for me.

Comment: have you tried in different browsers. or it might b due to extension compatibility with your magento version.

Comment: Yes I've tried it in different browsers and even at different locations. Getting same problem everywhere.

Comment: harshad do u embed any extension recently in magento. if yes did you check the version of that extension compatibility with your magento store version.

Comment: No I didn't install any extension from the beginning till now.

Answer (score 0):

Disable mod_pagespeed

Pagespeed processes a "cached" instance of your content with an abbreviation, i.e if this is the normal file.

> image.css

It will be set as follows.

> image.pagespeed.css

The above is a very simply example, but already you can see where the underlying issue is. This can cause improper static content loading due to not being able to be found via the core pathing, due to the fact that those are temporarily. This is an inherit problem with Mod_Pagespeed, ergo why we advise keeping it disabled.

the ansewer of fast comet support, and it solved my problem